# Using node FFI to import types from .so

Tags: javascript, node.js, rust, node-ffi

NodeFFI can be used to pull C files (specifically a .so) and read code from them. On that I had 2 questions. If I define a type in rust, will that show up as a type in javascript? Furthermore, is there anyway to use functions without setting parameter values (without the `'function': [ 'int', [ 'int', 'int' ] ]`? If not how would I "declare" a type from the .so file?

Comment: You seem to be confused. A `.so` file is a dynamic library, containing executable code. It may or may not have a C-compatible ABI, but it's definitely not a "C file". If you want to invoke Rust code from Node.js, see e.g. [this tutorial](https://blog.logrocket.com/rust-and-node-js-a-match-made-in-heaven/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I define a type in rust, will that show up as a type in javascript?

No. For one, the type system in JavaScript is very different from that in Rust. For another, a `.so` file cannot export any types at all. The memory layout of the types is expected to be known to the caller. In C, it would be declared in a header file (`.h`) that is provided along with the `.so` file.

> Furthermore, is there anyway to use functions without setting parameter values (without the 'function': [ 'int', [ 'int', 'int' ] ]? If not how would I "declare" a type from the .so file?

As explained above: you don't.

But you can use the [`node-bindgen`](https://crates.io/crates/node-bindgen) crate to generate Node.js wrapper code to invoke Rust code from Node.js relatively easily. This doesn't do what you asked, but it probably does what you need ;)

Comment: Thank you so much! I had a follow question when reading through this, is it possible to use bindgen on an entire rust library?

Comment: I think you'll have to add `#[node_bindgen]` to every type and function you want to export.